# Can somebody identify this pixel font? Reminds me of Space Invaders, but can't find it

Tags: font-identification

The closest fonts I've found are [Redensek](http://www.dafont.com/redensek.font) and [Kroeger](http://www.dafont.com/craig-kroeger.d840), but they are not the one in the image.

I'm looking for the font for "WINNER" and "OUTSTANDING ACHIEVEMENT".

I tried several font-identification services. Nothing came up.

[image: font sample]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[**04b03**](http://www.dafont.com/04b-03.font) by [04](http://www.dafont.com/04.d4):

[image: 04b03 font sample]

The V looked unique, so I focused on that while scrolling through the [bitmap category](http://www.dafont.com/bitmap.php?text=ACHIEVEMENT) on dafont.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be [xerxes regular low](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/testpilot/xerxes/regular-low/)

[image]

Comment: Close, but not the one. Look at the 'M' and the 'T'. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Also, the 'C' is different: the horizontal sections are three 'pixels' wide in this font but only two 'pixels' in the font in the question.